# Marshalling Date type

Tags: marshalling, vb6-migration

I'm trying to marshal a VB6 structure but I don't know how to marshal the Date type ex:
DateSaved As Date

and the following array of strings:
FASTNESSNAME(1 To 6) As String * 16

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in VB6 are very similar to dates in .NET (both are 8 bytes) so you should marshal as System.DateTime.

Fixed length strings and 1 based arrays are not supported as such in .NET. For the fixed length strings you could just use a custom .NET class?

As an addition to this you can use `<VBFixedString(20)>` to define a fixed string, but this doesn't work in the same way as you would expect in VB6. If you use this in a structure:

```
Private Structure FixedStr
    <VBFixedString(20)> Dim strTest As String
End Structure
```

And then use in your code - you can get differing results:

```
Dim fs As FixedStr
fs.strTest = "1234567890123456789012345"

MsgBox(Len(fs)) '<- Shows 20
MsgBox(Len(fs.strTest)) '<- Shows 25
```

Comment: As an addition to this you can use <VBFixedString(20)> to define a fixed string, but this doesn't work in the same way as you would expect in VB6. If you use this in a structure: